# How to add Real Attributes to Shapefile using pyqgis?

Tags: python, qgis, shapefile, pyqgis

I created the Qmarxan plugin using the fTools plugin as an example base. When I create a new shapefile using the QgsVectorFileWriter function I don't have any difficulty specifying a "Real" field with a width of 24 and a precision of 15. However when adding fields to an existing shapefile the addAttribute call to to a vector layer complains if the field is specified with a length greater than 20 and a precision greater that 5.

Can anyone tell me why this limitation exists and how get around it?

Thanks

TSW

Answer (score 1):

That's the Shapefile (or dbf) standard if I'm not mistaken. The GUI for creating a new Shapefile has the same restrictions.

You'll have to change to a different vector format if you want/need that kind of fields.

Comment: Concur. There's a discussion here - http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=9&f=85&t=253586 - and if you want the dbase file specs, they're here: http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm - it can only store  8 bytes in a double (I'm guessing that's what a "real" is). Try using SpatiaLite.